# What makes database connection expensive?

Tags: database, database-connection, dbconnection

We all seem to know that database connections are expensive and we try
to reduce the number of database trips as much as possible.
But Why should one care about it **??**

**This may sound like a stupid question:** 
 What makes a database connection expensive? and how it affects the overall performance.

> - Is it memory intensive?
> - CPU-intensive?
> - does it use a lot of bandwidth?
> - Or none of these?

can someone please explain it with all technical depth.

Comment: I don't know enough to explain it in technical depth but my understanding is if you db is hosted over the network creating new connections requires handshakes with multiple machines across the network and this makes the new database connection expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @UlugToprak, but this is what i already familiar about :)